# Spring Cloud Stream Reactive - How to do the Error Handling in case of reactive stream pipeline?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

How to do the **error handling for the reactive stream pipeline**. Like

- Application Error Handling (ex: errorChannel)
- System Error Handling (working with DLQ, reprocessing etc)

The current documentation only describes error handling for the non-reactive pipeline. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Fishtown.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_application_error_handling

> Spring cloud stream has done pretty easy for the users by providing simple configs for the error handling scenarios. It would be great if the same error handling usecases (with same configs) work for the **reactive stream pipeline** as well. The use cases and the respective config details as below:

- @StreamListner("errorChannel") annotation for the global error handling
- @KafkaListener(id="bar", topics = "reactive-stream-error-topic")
- Configs for the DLQ and producing failed messages to the error topics 
  *spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.enableDlq=true
  spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.dlqName=reactive-stream-error-topic*

The example from the documentation works fine with spring-cloud-stream **but the same thing gives an error for reactive pipeline**. Any guidelines in this direction would be of great help for the community. Thanks in advance!

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class ReactiveStreamSinkApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ReactiveStreamSinkApplication.class, args);
}

@StreamListener
public void receive(@Input(Sink.INPUT) Flux<String> inputFlux) {
    inputFlux.subscribe(System.out::println);
    throw new RuntimeException("BOOM!");
}

@StreamListener("errorChannel")
public void error(Message<?> message) {
    // log the error msg
    System.out.println("Handling ERROR: " + message);
}

@KafkaListener(id="bar", topics = "reactive-stream-error-topic")
public void error(String in) {
    System.out.println(in + " from DLQ");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply.

First, you have a problem in your code and a way you are treating how exception may be thrown from the reactive stream. Basically you are dealing with a declarative handler which is treated quite different. In your code the `receive` method will be invoked only once during the startup and initialization. So throwing exception from it is not at all equal to the exception thrown during the stream processing, which is the error handling mechanism you are inquiring about was designed for. But. . .

That aside. . .

With introduction of [Spring Cloud Function](https://spring.io/blog/2018/08/28/spring-cloud-stream-fishtown-m2-2-1-0-m2-release-announcement) programming model we are considering shifting attention from reactive module all together since Spring Cloud Function already provides support for reactive programming model. 
So consider the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class ReactiveStreamSinkApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReactiveStreamSinkApplication.class,
        "--spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=myconsumer");
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Flux<String>> myconsumer() {
        return stream -> stream.subscribe(value -> {
            if ("foo".equals(value)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("BOOM!");
            }
            System.out.println("Received value: " + value);
        });
    }

    @StreamListener("errorChannel")
    public void error(Message<?> message) {
        // log the error msg
        System.out.println("Handling ERROR: " + message);
    }
}
```

Try that and let us know.

Comment: Excited to try out the Spring Cloud Function in the pipeline. I will try your suggestion and keep you updated on the test results. Thank you!

Comment: It works partially. I can see the error message in my @StreamListener("errorChannel") method. But the failed message don't go to the DLQ ie error-topic. The same configurations work fine in the non-reactive stream application.

Comment: In addition, there's new error popped up, The exception track is this  java.lang.ClassCastException: ReactiveStreamSinkApplication$$Lambda cannot be cast to java.util.function.Function
This is due to the return type of SCF Consumer<Flux<String>>. It worked when I changed the return type to without Flux i.e. Consumer<String>. This seems a big problem. Since we would like to have Flux to do more declarative style programming inside myconsumer() method. Could you please check on this. Thank you!

Comment: @MansinghShitole please see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1539 as the issue was fixed. Give it a try and let us know.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It works! No more class cast exception and I can use Consumer<Flux<String>>. But unfortunately, error handling not working again due to this fix.  Before (without Flux), after the RuntimeException thrown - the error used to propagate back to the errorChannel. Now the Consumer Flux just gets cancelled and now the flow stops their only. I think its bug or we need to find out another way to handle this. Colud you please check on this. Thank you.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky this seems like a pretty big shift, at least there should be a work around for services that cannot be fragmented to single functions but yet using reactor.

Comment: @BasharAliLabadi I am not sure I fully understand what you mean by _. . .cannot be fragmented to single functions. . ._ All we are doing is asking you to change the signature of your existing method and remove no longer needed annotations. Reactive support is natively provided by SCF so for us it's a natural shift to eliminate redundancy. Your actual code is untouched.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky does this `"--spring.cloud.stream.function.definition"` allow multiple function definitions in the same single spring boot app or do I need to create an app per function ? if it does, then I apologize for my misunderstanding (I haven't found an example of it with many definitions). some apps may have multiple stream listeners

Comment: The reason why it is called  `*...definition` is because it allows you to compose a handler out of multiple function beans using coma or pipe character. For example `--spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=foo|bar|baz`

Comment: @MansinghShitole "Now the Consumer Flux just gets cancelled and now the flow stops their only." We have got this scenario - what can be done from here?
I see this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1922